# A book about the palmaceae

Tags: book-recommendation

I hope this isn't inappropriate for the forum - I'm trying to find a book that I read several decades ago, possibly 40 years or so. As I recall, it was a systematic treatment of the whole of the palmaceae. The title was fairly brief, possible just the word 'Palms'; however, I don't think it was this one [Martius: The Book of Palms](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Martius-Book-Palms-Walter-Lack/dp/3836556235/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=palms&qid=1590312656&s=books&sr=1-3). (I could be wrong, though.) Any ideas?